# Как дать доступ к сайту на java Servlet API с домашнего компьютера?

Tags: java, сервер, tomcat, servlet, j2ee

Задача следующая: дать доступ к учебным "pet" проектам с внешней машины наименее трудозатратным способом.

Исходные данные:

- Интернет: Динамический ip. Остальные данные любые.
- Операционная система: Windows. Хоть 98/NT, хоть 10. Не суть важно, но не Linux семейство.
- Сервер приложений: TomCat.
- Web сервер: он же.

В общем: как начинающему java-программисту выложить в сеть свои труды, что бы похвастаться перед друзьями? Что бы попроще и с наиболее распространенными начальными условиями.

Comment: Никак! Без выделенного IP никак. Используйте условно бесплатные хостниги.

Comment: Подключение PPPoE? Подключение обеспечивается маршрутизатором или комп сам его устанавливает?

Comment: @Victor, а DinDNS как же?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, пусть будет ethernet с подключением на прямую. В идеале бы wifi маршрутизатор.

Comment: Как мне кажется DinDNS, это уже костыли. Нет, конечно, похвастать друзьям и забыть - пойдет, но юзать такое постоянно...

Comment: @Victor, речь не идет о милионной посещаемости. Я хочу хвастаться перед друзьями в 3 запроса в год. Я не хочу лишней головной боли. Принимаются любые варианты, подходящие под начальные условия, минимизация головной боли приветствуется.

Comment: Ну вот, про DynDNS вы уже знаете. За чем дело стало?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, за ответом на вопрос)) Я сам не занимался, но думаю, что подводные камни есть везде. И если будет хороший ответ типа краткого гайда, то очень многие ребята, которые только начинают, будут благодарны.

Comment: Stackoverflow - не место для инструкции по настройке динамического DNS,

Comment: а вопрос только в настройке dns на динамический ip? Больше ничего делать не надо?

Comment: Может быть ещё открыть доступ к порту в брандмауэре. Это уже от особенностей вашей системы зависит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться вот таким сервисом [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/). Но вам понадобится установить [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). Это сервис позволяет создать временный туннель на вашу локальную машину.

1. Установить [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2. Установить **localtunnel** `npm install -g localtunnel`
3. Запустить ваш сервер
4. Запустить **localtunnel** `lt -p <порт на котором ваш сервер слушает>`
5. В ответ вы получите примерно такой **URL** `https://mbksrbelyb.localtunnel.me`

Comment: Спасибо. Все же есть варианты.